# How do I integrate this expression: $\int{2x\,dx\over x^3+x^{2/3}}$?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

How do I integrate this expression:
 $\displaystyle\int{2x\,dx\over x^3+x^{2/3}}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $u=x^{1/3}$, then $u^3=x$ so $dx=3u^2 du$ and now your integrand is a rational function.

Comment: On that note: $u^7+1=(u+1)(u^6-u^5+u^4-u^3+u^2-u+1)$. I wish the OP luck with his integration...

Comment: Yes, [the answer](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%202x%20%2F%20(x%5E3%20%2B%20x%5E\(2%2F3\)\)%20dx&t=crmtb01) is not a nice one.